# Controlling the probability of how sprites are added to a scene in AndEngine

Tags: java, android, sprite, andengine

I am trying to control the percentage at which sprites are picked to be added to a scene for my game.

I have four sprites that are picked based on the higher percentage. I would like to be able to change the percentages throughout game play. I need a sprite to be added to the scene each time the method is called. i have a timer that calls the method about every 2 seconds. I need s sprite to be added each time based on the percentage.

Here is what I have so far, but isn't working correctly. Increasing the percentages aren't increasing the probability of a sprite being added. It is increasing the wrong one sometimes, and sometimes not working at all. I know there has to be a better more easier way to do this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is my method where I add a sprite to the scene

```
private void addSprite() {
    switch (pickSprite()) {
    // Persons Sprite with area touched code
    case 1:
        red_Sprite = red_pool.obtainPoolItem();
        SequenceEntityModifier loop1 = new SequenceEntityModifier(
                    new RotationModifier(.5f, 0, -5),
                    new RotationModifier(.5f, -5, 5),
                    new RotationModifier(.5f, 5, 0));
        red_Sprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(loop1));
        scene.registerTouchArea(red_Sprite);
        if (!red_Sprite.hasParent())
            scene.getFirstChild().attachChild(red_Sprite);
        else
            red_Sprite.setVisible(true);
        red_personList.add(red_Sprite);
        break;
    case 2:
    // Persons Sprite with area touched code
        green_Sprite = green_pool.obtainPoolItem();
        SequenceEntityModifier loop2 = new SequenceEntityModifier(
                    new RotationModifier(.5f, 0, -5),
                    new RotationModifier(.5f, -5, 5),
                    new RotationModifier(.5f, 5, 0));
        green_Sprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(loop2));
        scene.registerTouchArea(green_Sprite);
        if (!green_Sprite.hasParent())
            scene.getFirstChild().attachChild(green_Sprite);
        else
            green_Sprite.setVisible(true);
        green_personList.add(green_Sprite);
        break;
    case 3:
    // Persons Sprite with area touched code
        orange_Sprite = orange_pool.obtainPoolItem();
        SequenceEntityModifier loop = new SequenceEntityModifier(
                    new RotationModifier(.5f, 0, -5),
                    new RotationModifier(.5f, -5, 5),
                    new RotationModifier(.5f, 5, 0));
        orange_Sprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(loop));
        scene.registerTouchArea(orange_Sprite);
        if (!orange_Sprite.hasParent())
            scene.getFirstChild().attachChild(orange_Sprite);
        else
            orange_Sprite.setVisible(true);
        orange_personList.add(orange_Sprite);
        break;
    case 4:
    // Persons Sprite with area touched code
        blue_Sprite = blue_pool.obtainPoolItem();
        SequenceEntityModifier loop4 = new SequenceEntityModifier(
                    new RotationModifier(.5f, 0, -5),
                    new RotationModifier(.5f, -5, 5),
                    new RotationModifier(.5f, 5, 0));
        blue_Sprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(loop4));
        scene.registerTouchArea(blue_Sprite);
        if (!blue_Sprite.hasParent())
            scene.getFirstChild().attachChild(blue_Sprite);
        else
            blue_Sprite.setVisible(true);
        blue_personList.add(blue_Sprite);
        break;
    }
```

Here is my pick sprite method:

```
public int pickSprite() {
    double rand = Math.random();
    for (int i = 0; i < mOdds.length; i++) {
        if (rand < mOdds[i])
            return i;
        rand -= mOdds[i];
    }
    return -1; // should never reach this
}
```

Here is my method where i try to increase the odds or percentage of sprites being added.

```
public void increaseOdds(int index, double value) {
    double valueFromIndex = mOdds[index];
    mOdds[index] += value;
    // Make sure odds don't turn mOdds to less than zero
    if (mOdds[index] < 0.0) {
        value = value - mOdds[index];
        mOdds[index] = 0.0;
    } else if (mOdds[index] > 1.0) {
        value = mOdds[index] - 1;
        mOdds[index] = 1.0;
    }
    double changeToOthers = value / 3;
    double extraForNext = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < mOdds.length; i++) {
        if (i != index) {
            mOdds[i] -= changeToOthers;
            if (mOdds[i] < 0) {
                extraForNext = mOdds[i];
                mOdds[i] = 0.0;
            } else if (mOdds[i] > 1) {
                extraForNext = 1 - mOdds[i];
                mOdds[i] = 1.0;
            } else {
                mOdds[i] += extraForNext;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things with `increaseOdds()` that I can see causing problems. Assume you're calling it on `index 0`, `value 0.6`, and that `mOdds[0]` currently equals 0.8. Your code then adds the two, giving `mOdds[0] = 1.4`. Then you would subtract 1, assigning `value = 0.4`, even though you really only changed it by 0.2. So you end up adding 0.2 to the index, and splitting up -0.4 for the other three, causing them to not equal 1.

Also, what happens if you the last element is the one that gives you an "extra" amount? You need to check for that and assign it to another after you loop through the array.

Try this on for size and see how it works out for you. I ran it through on pen and paper with some odd numbers designed to test it, and it seems to hold up:

**EDIT**: Changed some code.

```
public void changeOdds(int index, double value) 
{
    double old = mOdds[index];
            mOdds[index] = value;

    if(mOdds[index] > 1)
        mOdds[index] = 1;
    if(mOdds[index] < 0)
        mOdds[index] = 0;   

    double changeToOthers = (mOdds[index] - old) / -3.0;
    double extra = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<mOdds.length;i++)
    {
        if(i == index)
            continue;
        double add = changeToOthers + extra;
        if(mOdds[i] + add > 1)
        {
            extra = 1 - mOdds[i];
            mOdds[i] = 1;
        } else if(mOdds[i] + add < 0)
        {       
            extra = -mOdds[i];
            mOdds[i] = 0
        } else
        {
            mOdds += add;
            extra = 0;
        }
    }   
            // if there's still a negative extra, assign it to the first non-index that can take it and stop
    if(extra < 0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<mOdds.length;i++)
        {
            if(i == index)
                continue;
            if(mOdds[i] + extra >= 0)
            {
                mOdds[i] += extra;
                extra = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
            // ditto for positive extras
    if(extra > 0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<mOdds.length;i++)
        {
            if(i == index)
                continue;
            if(mOdds[i] + extra <= 1)
            {
                mOdds[i] += extra;
                extra = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but when i try increaseOdds(0, .38); it still changes the outcome to something like .48.

Comment: What was it before you called `increaseOdds()`? I'm assuming that function is supposed to add it to the current odds, not replace it.

Comment: Oh no, it is suppose to replace the current odd

Comment: ... Ok, for future reference, when you name a function `increaseOdds` and the first line is `mOdds[index] += value;`, people are going to naturally assume it's supposed to _add_ them, not replace. Edited my code to reflect.